# Multiply categories and bind them to Database Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-2.1

i need help with my forms that i create, i created 5 forms in a twig file and created a controller , how can i bind my value from the forms to database, when i bind now it displays me only one Value form the 5 times , but i need 5 times to be different value :(, please help , I stuck on this thing all day already..

my twig file:

```
<div class="new-test">
     <h2>New test </h2>
     <form action="{{ path('test.create') }}" method="post">

        Test name:   <input type="text" name="name"/><br>
        Category 1<input type="text" name="category-new" >
        <div id="customWidget">
            <div id="colorSelector1"><div style="background-color: #00ff00"></div>  
          </div>
            <div id="colorpickerHolder1"></div>
        </div>

        Category 2<input type="text" name="category-new" ><br>
        Category 3<input type="text" name="category-new" ><br>
        Category 4<input type="text" name="category-new" ><br>
        Category 5<input type="text" name="category-new" ><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

my controller:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/add/test", requirements={"name" = "\s+"}, name="test.create")
 * @Method("Post")
 * @return array
 */
public function createAction()
{
    $success = 0;
    $name = $this->getRequest()->get('name');




    if( !empty($name) )
    {
        $test = new Test();
        $test->setName($this->getRequest()->get('name'));

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($test);
        $em->flush();

        $success = 'Test '.$test->getName().' was created';
    }
    else
    {
        $success = 'Test name can not be empty';
    }

      $category = $this->getRequest()->get('category-new');
     for ($i=0; $i<=5; $i++){
     if( !empty($category) )   
       {
        $categoryName = new Category();
        $categoryName->setName($this->getRequest()->get('category-new'));


        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($categoryName);
        $em->flush();

        $success = ' Category '.$categoryName->getName().$i.' was created';

       }

        else
     {
        $success = 'Test name can not be empty';
    }
   }
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('test.new'));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template:

> ```
>     Category 1<input type="text" name="category-new[]" >
>     <div id="customWidget">
>         <div id="colorSelector1"><div style="background-color: #00ff00"></div>  
>       </div>
>         <div id="colorpickerHolder1"></div>
>     </div>
>
>     Category 2<input type="text" name="category-new[]" ><br>
>     Category 3<input type="text" name="category-new[]" ><br>
>     Category 4<input type="text" name="category-new[]" ><br>
>     Category 5<input type="text" name="category-new[]" ><br>
> ```

It`s meen, that your controller take array with name category-new

> ```
> /**
>  * @Route("/add/test")
>  * 
>  * @return array
>  */
> public function createAction()
> {
>     $success = 0;
>     $name = $this->getRequest()->get('name');
>
>     if (!empty($name)) {
>         $test = new Test();
>         $test->setName($name);
>
>         $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
>         $em->persist($test);
>         $em->flush();
>
>         $success = 'Test ' . $test->getName() . ' was created';
>     } else {
>         $success = 'Test name can not be empty';
>     }
>
>     $categoryList = array_map('trim', $this->getRequest()->get('category-new'));
>
>     foreach ($categoryList as $category) {
>         if (!empty($category)) {
>             $categoryName = new Category();
>             $categoryName->setName($category);
>
>             $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
>             $em->persist($categoryName);
>             $em->flush();
>
>             $success = ' Category ' . $category . ' was created';
>
>         } else {
>             $success = 'Test category-new may not be empty';
>         }
>     }
>     return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('test_create'));
> }
> ```

Some words

> Route("/add/test", requirements={"name" = "\s+"}, name="test.create")

requirements not need for you
name of this action will be project_bundlename_controller_action for you {project}_{bundlename}_test_create whereis i dont know you project name and bundle name - its not a diffucult i think for you. And some code :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if i understand correctly. You want to have inputs with name 'category-new' that have different value. If so, you have problem in form view:

```
Category *<input type="text" name="category-new" ><br>
```

name should have bracket at the end name="category-new[]" or name="category-new[1]" for category 1, name="category-new[2]" for category 2, and so on.